# API Key Authentication Python example raises TypeError

Tags: python-3.x, coinbase-api

API Key Authentication Python example in the [site](https://developers.coinbase.com/docs/wallet/api-key-authentication) raises a TypeError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test-coin.py", line 39, in <module>
    r = requests.get(api_url + 'user', auth=auth)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 72, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 506, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 439, in prepare_request
    p.prepare(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 309, in prepare
    self.prepare_auth(auth, url)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 540, in prepare_auth
    r = auth(self)
  File "test-coin.py", line 25, in __call__
    signature = hmac.new(self.secret_key, message, hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/hmac.py", line 146, in new
    return HMAC(key, msg, digestmod)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/hmac.py", line 46, in __init__
    raise TypeError("key: expected bytes or bytearray, but got %r" % type(key).__name__)
TypeError: key: expected bytes or bytearray, but got 'str'
```

The problem is in this part of the code:

```
def __call__(self, request):
    ...
    signature = hmac.new(self.secret_key, message, hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
```

We need to encode `self.secret_key` and `message`. Replace the line:

`signature = hmac.new(self.secret_key.encode(), message.encode(), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()`

Fixed the issue. I wonder if anyone else stumbled with that error?

Comment: Is this a question or have you solved it?

Comment: @JohnGlenn I solved it. But, I was wonder if anyone else had this problem or if is something related with Python version (or hmac lib version).